# JQuery EasyUI datagrid url being called with a POST even when method=GET

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I am just starting out JQuery and easyui. The datagrid control looks super but my URL is being called with a POST everytime,  even though I am setting the method to GET.

```
 <table id="dg" title="Plan details" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:550px;height:250px"
    url="/Plans"
    toolbar="#toolbar"
    method="GET"
    rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
            <th field="name" width="50">Name</th>
            <th field="description" width="100">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div id="toolbar">

</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Cormac Keogh

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I solved it by adding: data-options="method: 'get'" instead.