# Cannot load JQuery EasyUI datagrid using JavaScript approach

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using JQuery EasyUI's datagrid is a very basic implementation.

If I use the inline approach to loading in the data all is fine and the data shows (note the JSON API is working as I have enabled CORS on the server so that's not the issue):

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid"
        data-options="url:'https://www.driverlive.co.uk/rest/api/PushMessage/GetPushDriverMessagesList?DeviceId=a99f8a977696bfb9&DateFrom=2014-10-27T00:00:00&DateTo=2015-11-11T00:00:00',method:'get',singleSelect:true,fit:true,fitColumns:true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'PushDriverMessageDBID'" width="80">Item ID</th>
            <th data-options="field:'PushDriverMessageGuid'" width="100">PushDriverMessageGuid</th>
            <th data-options="field:'AppKey',align:'right'" width="80">AppKey</th>
            <th data-options="field:'PushNotificationMessage',align:'right'" width="300">PushNotificationMessage</th>
            <th data-options="field:'Sender'" width="150">Sender</th>
            <th data-options="field:'MessageDated',align:'center'" width="50">MessageDated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If I attempt the JavaScript way of loading the datagrid I get no data but I cannot understand why?

```
// Dispatching DataGrid
var JSONDispatchingURL = "https://www.driverlive.co.uk/rest/api/PushMessage/GetPushDriverMessagesList?DeviceId=a99f8a977696bfb9&DateFrom=2014-10-27T00:00:00&DateTo=2015-11-11T00:00:00";
        $('#DGDispatching').datagrid({
            url: JSONDispatchingURL,
            columns: [[
                { field: 'PushDriverMessageDBID', title: 'PushDriverMessageDBID', width: 100 },
                { field: 'PushDriverMessageGuid', title: 'PushDriverMessageGuid', width: 100 },
                { field: 'AppKey', title: 'AppKey', width: 100 },
                { field: 'PushNotificationMessage', title: 'PushNotificationMessage', width: 100 },
                { field: 'Sender', title: 'Sender', width: 100 },
                { field: 'MessageDated', title: 'MessageDated', width: 100}
            ]]
        });
```

I have the same result with the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b6fxs2v2/1/

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php so I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 0):

OK. I fired up Fiddler and it showed that JQuery EasyUI was calling the service with POST rather than GET. The REST API was therefore responding with a 405. The response was specifically {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

I found similar [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101497/jquery-easyui-datagrid-url-being-called-with-a-post-even-when-method-get) and then modified my code as below. This then worked!

```
var JSONDispatchingURL = "https://www.driverlive.co.uk/rest/api/PushMessage/GetPushDriverMessagesList?DeviceId=a99f8a977696bfb9&DateFrom=2014-10-27T00:00:00&DateTo=2015-11-11T00:00:00";
        $('#DGDispatching').datagrid({
            url: JSONDispatchingURL,
            method: 'get',
            columns: [[
                { field: 'PushDriverMessageDBID', title: 'PushDriverMessageDBID', width: 100 },
                { field: 'PushDriverMessageGuid', title: 'PushDriverMessageGuid', width: 100 },
                { field: 'AppKey', title: 'AppKey', width: 100 },
                { field: 'PushNotificationMessage', title: 'PushNotificationMessage', width: 100 },
                { field: 'Sender', title: 'Sender', width: 100 },
                { field: 'MessageDated', title: 'MessageDated', width: 100 }
            ]]
        });
```