# JQuery EasyUI Datagrid works with one web service but not another (same code same servers)

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, jquery-easyui

I am using JQuery EasyUI's datagrid is a very basic implementation.

Following on from my [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463014/cannot-load-jquery-easyui-datagrid-using-javascript-approach) (where I managed to get JQuery EasyUI's datagrid to load in data from my webservice using the JavaScript approach). I now have a very bizarre issue that I cannot understand.

In short, one web service works, another doesn't but the code is basically identical and both web services are hosted on the same server and use CORS so we have no same origin issues. I really cannot see any visible difference between the code and their execution. One works, the other does not... I can only assume it is something to do with the server API response but the structure matches, the are both generated off the same site and same server... all very odd... I'm using .NET Web API 2 to output the JSON.

Here's the working version:

```
<table id="DGInProgress" class="easyui-datagrid"
        data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,url:'https://www.driverlive.co.uk/rest/api/PushMessage/GetPushDriverMessagesList?DeviceId=a99f8a977696bfb9&DateFrom=2014-10-27T00:00:00&DateTo=2015-11-11T00:00:00',method:'get'">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'MessageDated',width:80">Dated</th>
            <th data-options="field:'PushNotificationMessage',width:100">Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here's the code that doesn't

```
<table id="DGInProgress" class="easyui-datagrid"
        data-options="singleSelect:true,collapsible:true,url:'https://www.driverlive.co.uk/dispatch/api/BookingsInProgressLite/GetBookingsLite?dateTimeFrom=2014-01-01&dateTimeTo=2015-03-01&limit=100&json=true',method:'get'">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-options="field:'BookingReference',width:80">BookingReference</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

As you can see, both follow the same markup and when I view the web service JSON it too follows the same structure.

Additionally Fiddler shows that the 'get' request was made and that the JSON was returned. So why will the grid show the data for the PushMessages API and not the Bookings API?...

[image: Working JSON]

[image: Not working JSON]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non working response header doesn't allow CORS - it's missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Cripes! Yes, I see this in Fiddler now. I guess my real problem is why is CORS not working for this project but is fine for the other. I have now removed the reference, cleaned, rebuilt, added and repeated and double checked all the online resources to ensure I am adding CORS correctly - despite this the header is still missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value...

Answer (score 0):

@Kyle provided the answer as to why this was not working but I wanted to list another answer as detailing the cause and the resolution.

There were two issues here.

Firstly, I had followed [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) initially for the first project and all worked well. I had skimmed over it for the second project and although I had installed CORS via Nuget Package Management I had failed to add the line:

```
// New code
config.EnableCors();
```

In AppStart WebApiConfig.cs

After I did this, thinking all would be fine, it still didn't work.

I tried removing the reference to CORS, cleaning, rebuilding, adding it and repeat... still no joy. I then re-referenced the entire Web API 2 library including CORS and still no joy. I finally used the package manager console window and noticed in the text that there was a dependency on a Json package that needed me to restart Visual Studio.

I did this and it then started working.

Another 'Gotcha' was that I was testing to see if CORS was now causing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to show in Fiddler. However I was doing so by accessing the API directly through my browser. This never showed the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header so I was fooled into believing it was still not working. I needed to request the service through the web application in order to see the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header appear in Fiddler.